# como enviar parametros del tipo x-www-urlencoded en un cuerpo json en osb12c

Tags: webservice, post, osb

Necesito exponer en osb12c un webservice para hacer login, este servicio espera un  `x-www-form-urlencoded`, realice la exposicion, la razón por la que estoy aquí es  que al enviar las credenciales como `x-www-urlencoded` estas quedan expuestas en la url.

¿Hay forma de evitar que esa información vaya en el url y viaje en el cuerpo por ejemplo?

Intente que el servicio enviara las credenciales en el cuerpo JSON pero no autentica y responde que las credenciales no son validas, asumo que es porque espera `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

La petición actual en postman es esta

```
POST https://url:port/maui/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 37
Host: url:port
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

j_username=user&j_password=pass
```

en los log se ve algo como esto:

```
url - - [03/Jan/2022:16:08:05 -0300] "POST /maui/j_spring_security_check?j_username=user&j_password=pass HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Agradezco que alguien pudiera sugerirme que hacer para solucionar este fallo de seguridad y poder enviarle al servicio lo que necesita